# How to block URL to open my android app?

Tags: android

My android app allows to open other website like "http://www.google.com" in a web browser from app. And my code is below.

```
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But this gives me a problem. In the email or text message, click any website link, there will be a choice to open from my app. See the picture I posted. If I click on www.google.com in the text message, I will get a choice to open from my app.

I don't want the popup shows my app. How to handle this? Please help. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: @CommonsWare I think he wants his app to not show up in the Chooser on clicking a url.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid that, unless you specifically know what browser the user wants to use. And you don't know that.

You could have a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) activity/fragment bundled in your application that will display webpages for you. That way you'd have full control. Here's a [`guide on WebView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your app is being displayed in the *Complete Action Using* chooser because of your intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and particularly because you've specified just a "scheme" entry, with no specific "host".  This would in effect offer any web URL intent to open in your app.

Without understanding what your intended behavior exactly is, you can delete the <data> nodes from your intent-filter to remove your app from the Chooser.

Or alternatively, you might want specific URL's to offer your app in the Chooser, like http://yourserver.com and https://yourserver.com, for this you could alter your intent-filter as follows:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="yourserver.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to block URLs of other websites in your android app for download purpose then search for the `iConstants.java` file in your project and write the following code:

```
public interface iConstants {
    public static final String[] DISABLE_DOWNLOADING = {"URL", };
    public static final String WEB_DISABLE = "We cannot allow to download videos form this website.";

}
```