# How to prevent certain url from opening my app

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using the below code to open my app when user click in a link:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mywebsite.com"      android:pathPrefix="/feed/" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mywebsite.com" android:pathPrefix="/feed/" />
</intent-filter>
```

But my problem is that, I am showing an image with a link to it in a webview in my app. When the user clicks in the image, it will open the activity which cause an error.

I have "/img/" in my Image url. So any possible way to avoid the url with "/img/"  opening my app?

Comment: there is a question posted literally minutes ago that asks basically this exact question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438316/how-to-block-url-to-open-my-android-app

Comment: Add a `WebViewClient` to your `WebView`. Implement `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` on the `WebViewClient`. Have it decide what links to keep in the `WebView` and what links to launch using the normal `ACTION_VIEW` process.